# Can not get PHP to post info to database

Tags: php, mysql

I've written a script to post information into my database for I can't get it to post and need help pointing out what I'm missing.

my php post for looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * from departments";
$res = mysql_query($query);
echo '<div id="department" >';
echo '<form action="depedit.php" method="post">';
echo '<input type="text" placeholder="Search departments">';
echo '<br>';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div id="depadd">'; 
echo '<form>';
echo '<table width="0" border="0">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>Name:</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo "<select name='depid'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['depname']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo '</td>';
echo '  </tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '  <tr>';
echo '<td><label class="limit">Select Limit for active courses in Learning Locker:</label></td>';
echo '  </tr>';
echo '  <tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo "<select name='courselimit'>";
echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
echo "<option value='2'>2</option>";
echo "<option value='3'>3</option>";
echo "<option value='4'>4</option>";
echo "<option value='5'>5</option>";
echo "<option value='0'>Unlimited</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><input type="radio" id="1" name="senabled" value="1"/><label for="c1" class="required">Required<br>(Study Shredder Feature Enabled)</br></label></td>';
echo '<td><input type="radio" id="0" name="senabled" value="0"/><label for="c1" class="optional">Optional</label></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="orgid" value="'.$adminorgid.'"></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="createdby" value="'.$userid.'"></td>';
echo '</tr>';  
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><input type="hidden" name="timecreated" value="'.time(now).'"></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '  <tr>';
echo '    <td><button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button></td>';
echo '  </tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo "</form>";
echo '</div>';
```

depedit.php looks like this:

```
 $adddep = "INSERT INTO organization_dep (orgid,depid,courselimit,senabled,createdby,timecreated) VALUES ('".$_POST["orgid"].",".$_POST["depid"].",".$_POST["courselimit"].",".$_POST["senabled"].",".$_POST["createdby"].",".$_POST["timecreated"]."')";
    $res = mysql_query($adddep);

    if ($res === TRUE) {
        echo "Department added successfully";
    } else{
        printf("Could not create department");
    }
```

the correct information seems like its getting passed as the url displays the following information in it:

/index.php?depid=6&courselimit=3&senabled=1&orgid=9&createdby=1129&timecreated=1364005206

any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I'm sure its something simple that I'm just over looking.

Comment: ohhh my God, I have never someone abusing `echo` as much before,

Comment: never *seen someone ^

Comment: @PHPNooB Have you seen basically all wordpress plugins? Seriously though, this style of coding makes it really hard to figure out why your html acts funny... you might want to redo it without all the echos like this: https://gist.github.com/SeanJA/42ff21537e44d2a3943a

Comment: already removed 99.9% of the echos on Mohammads suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the values from the $_POST

```
('".$_POST["orgid"].",".$_POST["depid"].",".$_POST["courselimit"].",".$_POST["senabled"].",".$_POST["createdby"].",".$_POST["timecreated"]."')";
```

but your saying it is passed through the URL, this looks like you need to use $_GET to get the values

--- and one small tip you can use echo to print multiple lines it works. as long as you close it, in the end

e.g

```
echo " <html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
";
```

Comment: thank you for the tip about the multiple lines, I'll definitly use it to clean up the code. Still fairly new to this and learning as I go.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bunch of things to get right before this will be working:

1. Only the first form, which seems to be for searching departments, have method and action attributes
2. Since the second form does not have the action attribute, it is not submitting to depedit.php but to the same page that has the form.
3. Since the second form does not have the method attribute, it defaults to GET, and you are trying to read out POST variables in your PHP. If it was not using GET, you would not see those params in the resulting URL.
4. In your SQL insert statement, you must have single quotes around every single **text** value but **not** around int values. Now you have one single quote before the first value and one before the last which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

First: this portion will not be POSTed "depedit.php" because there is no submit

`echo '<form action="depedit.php" method="post">';
echo '<input type="text" placeholder="Search departments">';
echo '<br>';
echo '</form>';`

Second: this will never be POSTed to depedit.php, since your `<form>` does not have an action specifying "depedit.php"

```
echo '<form>';
echo '<table width="0" border="0">';
echo '<tr>';
//other codes
echo "</form>";
```

maybe you mean to remove the first `echo '</form>'(line 7)` and the second `<form>(line 10)`

Comment: Forms without an action and method do get submitted with a GET method apparently. :) . But I side with you. I wouldn't go that way ..

Comment: knew it was something stupid. lack of sleep, the second <form was supposed to be the one that I added the post action to. As soon as I moved it, I atleast got the error that it couldn't add the department. rearranging the error code so it gives me the actual error. I'll keep you posted. Thank you so much.

Comment: ok so the actual error i get is Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, but i counted 6 inputs. I'm sure its another ID10T error.

Comment: @user1837361 it's an error in your INSERT statement in depedit.php. If you didn't include an auto incrementing ID, try to include that in your columns and put the values as ' ' empty single quotes

Comment: the ID is auto incrementing. I took the values it was passing to the url by removing the form action temporarily and used phpadmin to do a manual insert and it went through fine. Any further ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: thanks for all the help everyone and the great advice. I was finally able to figure it out!